# IOS: NSString format

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, airprint

I have this code:

```
NSString *firstString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringToWrite] stringByPaddingToLength:40 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finallyString = @"";
    finallyString = [firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString];
```

with this code I have a text formatting of my string with two columns, but when I print these string with airPrint method they lost this text formatting.
Why in NSLog it's all ok and when I print in a paper it lost the text formatting?

code of print:

```
NSMutableString *printHead = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"words"];
for (int i = 0; i<myArray.count; i++)
{
    [printHead appendFormat:@"\n\n\n"];
    NSString *stringToWrite = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *firstString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringToWrite] stringByPaddingToLength:40 withString:@" " startingAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finallyString = @"";
    finallyString = [firstString stringByAppendingString:[[myArray objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:1]];
    [printHead appendString:finallyString];
    }
UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.delegate = self;

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
pic.printInfo = printInfo;

UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printHead];
textFormatter.startPage = 0;
//textFormatter.color = [UIColor redColor];
textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30.0, 30.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 8 * 72.0;
pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
[textFormatter release];


pic.showsPageRange = YES;

void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if (!completed && error) {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};

[pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: what font is it being printed in?

Comment: what´s the code for printing? maybe something is missing there

Answer (score 0):

NSLog() isn't something you should rely on for formatting. If you want your text to appear a certain way when printed, you'll want to draw it into a view. If you want the view to look different when printed compared to how it looks on the screen, implement `-drawRect:forViewPrintFormatter:` to draw the printed version.

Comment: ok but I don't want to see the view in my app, where can I put this view where I'll write my text formatted?

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain your answer?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think a view needs to be added to a window to be printable. Take a look at UIViewPrintFormatter.